# How to change the address of the string to the nth character of the string

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am a beginner, writing a program in 64-bit that is supposed to ask the user a string that is 8 char long, and "cut" n number of chars from the string based on user's input of n (less than or equal to 8). The result is not what I am expecting.

I am trying to change the address of the string to point to the char that comes n chars later in string. I already tried using rep movsb, but failed. I could use loops and jumps but I don't want to. I believe the way I am trying should be good enough. Also, using nasm for this program.

```
    section .bss
    num:    resw    2               ;Reserved for the number of char to be cut off

    section .data

    str:    db      "",0x00
    strLen: db      8                ; Length of string is 8


    section .text

    global  main
```

main:

```
    ;; Read user input
    mov     rax,0
    mov     rdi,0
    mov     rsi,str
    mov     rdx,strLen
    syscall

    ;; Get input for int 
    mov     rax,0
    mov     rdi,0
    mov     rsi,num
    syscall

    ;; Change the char to number
    mov     r10,[num]
    sub     r10,48
    mov     [num],r10

    ;; Edit the string address
    mov     rax,[num]
    lea     r10,[str+rax]
    mov     [str],r10

    ;; Show the edited string
    mov     rax,1
    mov     rdi,1
    mov     rsi,str
    syscall

    ;; Exit section.
    mov rax,60              ;calls sys_exit
    xor rdi,rdi             ;0 for no errors
    syscall                 ;system call
```

Actual result:

Enter string:

Assembly

Enter the number of chars to cut off:

3

This is what was entered

Assembly

Here is the text edited

▒J@

---

Expected:

Assembly

3

Assembly

embly

Comment: `str:    db      "",0x00` is already wrong. `""` reserves no space. If you want to allocate space for 8 characters you will need to do something like `str: db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` or use your assembler's allocation keywords. While adding to the address is a correct solution, you actually write the address into the buffer which is wrong and then proceed to print the whole string anyway due to `mov rsi,str`. Also you load 8 bytes from a 2 byte word.

Comment: @Jester, Thank you for your comment. I understood the issue with str, and am trying to solve it. Shows me nothing in the edited text, but working on it. However, I don't understand how I am loading 8 bytes from a 2 byte word ? Because I am not using that word for the string, but for the integer.

Comment: You have a single digit stored in `num` (it's 2 bytes for the newline I guess). But then you do `mov r10,[num]`. `r10` is a 8 byte register so you will load your digit, your newline and 6 other random bytes. While that's mostly harmless for the conversion, writing 8 bytes back into `num` will overwrite whatever is after it in memory and that is more likely to cause trouble. Later you do `mov rax,[num]` and that will definitely wreak havoc since you use that to index. You should use byte registers or zero extension.

Comment: @Jester Thank you! I understood the problem and solved it.